# Django - Create multiple different objects with relations in single Django endpoint

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to create a endpoint that creates multiple objects? what I've been doing instead is taking in request data and creating the objects one at a time and if one fails then delete the previously created entities, this seems really really hacky and there has to be a better way to create multiple objects. So essentially all `Post` need to be associated with a `Goal` so when a request comes it it'll be accompanied with post related data and goal related data in `request.data`. So it should create the `Goal` first then the `Post` associated with it. Is there a way to do this in one go? My assumption is creating a custom serializer to handle this, but not sure how to eloquently handle the case of when if `Post` fails to create I should delete `Goal`.

model.py

```
class Goal(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="goal_creator_uuid")
    goal_category = models.ForeignKey(GoalCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])

class Post(AbstractBaseModel):
    creator_uuid = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator_uuid")
    goal_uuid = models.ForeignKey(Goal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = post_body
```

view.py

```
def post(request):
    """
    POST endpoint for current user creating a goal update post
    """
    goal_serializer = GoalSerializer(data=request.data)
    if goal_serializer.is_valid():
        goal_obj = goal_serializer.save()
    else:
        # return 400 Response
    
    request.data['goal_uuid'] = str(goal_obj.uud)
    post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
    
    if post_serializer.is_valid():
        post_serializer.save()
    else:
        goal_obj.delete()
        # return 400 Response

   # return 200 Response
```

Comment: [This](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) might help

Comment: @BrianDestura thanks! Definitely helps with part of the problem. I still need to deal with the creating multiple objects part.

Comment: @BrianDestura actually this is useful but it might not solve my problem the way that I'd like, because if there's an error in the serializer I'd like to ideally return a 400 response with the reasoning why. I think `@atomic` only works when an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap those serializers in an atomic block with a `try...except` like this:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError


def post(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            goal_serializer = GoalSerializer(data=request.data)
            goal_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            goal_obj = goal_serializer.save()

            request.data['goal_uuid'] = str(goal_obj.uud)
            post_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
            post_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            post_serializer.save()

    except ValidationError as e:
        # return 400 Response with e as details

   # return 200 Response
```

When the serializer validation fails (or if any exception gets raised), it will automatically rollback everything within the `atomic` block. You can then catch the `ValidationError` and build a response you need.